# Javascript loop logic is incorrect

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, vb.net, dom

```js
function authorNumbering() {
    var authorDivs = document.getElementById('authorView').getElementsByTagName("div");
    var labels = [];
    var nameForLabels = ["Author 1", "Author 2", "Author 3", "Author 4", "Author 5", "Author 6", "Author 7"]; 
    for (var i = 0; i < authorDivs.length; i++) {
        var labelsFromDiv = authorDivs[i].getElementsByTagName("label");
        for (var x = 0; x < labelsFromDiv.length; x++) {
            if (!(typeof labelsFromDiv.item(x) === "undefined" || labelsFromDiv.item(x) == null)) { 
                labels[x] = labelsFromDiv.item(x);

            }
        }
        labels[i].innerHTML = nameForLabels[i];
    }
}
```

Essentially the function (or at least what it does in my head) goes through and gets a bunch of labels from the author divs. I then save the labels (which are not undefined or null) into an array. I now would like to be able to change the labels as shown above (at `x`) but for some reason `x` is always either 0 or 1. I've tried a couple things but I don't think I understand the logic enough to figure it out properly. `labels[]` also has duplicates within the array, how can I avoid having duplicates while still having two loops?

I'm new to JavaScript but I'm trying my best.

Edit 1: Wow, I really messed up what I was trying to do there. Thanks for the help I've updated the code.

What I want to do is rename the labels with a label from `nameForLabels` array. This works for the first label but then I receive the following error: `TypeError: labels[i] is undefined`

This is happening because `labels` never exceeds the length of 1, I think it gets rewritten every time rather than get written to the next position in the array. How come `x` never goes higher than 0?

What I would like to see is all the labels in the `labels` array get changed to those that are in the `nameForLabels` array. For example the label in `labels[0]` would become `Author 1`, and `labels[1]` would become `Author 2` and so on.

Edit 2: HTML example added:

```js
<div style="display: block;" id="authorView" class="form-horizontal">
    <div id="author0" class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-4 control-label"><label class="" for="author0" id="lblauthor0">Author 1:</label></div>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <div class="input-group"><input class="form-control" ... *keeps going with irrelevant information*
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="author1" class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-4 control-label"><label class="" for="author1" id="lblauthor1">Author 2:</label></div>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <div class="input-group"><input class="form-control" ... *keeps going with irrelevant information*
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="author2" class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-4 control-label"><label class="" for="author2" id="lblauthor2">Author 3:</label></div>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <div class="input-group"><input class="form-control" ... *keeps going with irrelevant information*
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="author3" class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-4 control-label"><label class="" for="author3" id="lblauthor3">Author 4:</label></div>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <div class="input-group"><input class="form-control" ... *keeps going with irrelevant information*
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="author4" class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-4 control-label"><label class="" for="author4" id="lblauthor4">Author 5:</label></div>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <div class="input-group"><input class="form-control" ... *keeps going with irrelevant information*
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It would help to show an example of the HTML markup you're parsing. Also, using the debugging tools in your browser would show you what's going on.

Comment: Ok, first step here is to find out what's going on. You need to use the debugger in your browser tools (F12 in FF/Chrome) Go to the Scripts/Sources tab and put a breakpoint on your first line ` var authorDivs = ...`. You should then be able to use the "Step Over" button to execute one line at a time and see what's happening. How many labes do you have for each author? If it's 2 or less, x _will_ always be 0 or 1...

Comment: And you are assigning only the text "Author 3" to the labels. The other texts are thrown away.

Comment: And one other tip... there's never a need to do `{ /* intentionally left blank */ }`. `if(conditions) {} else {a=1;}` is the same as `if(!(conditions)) {a=1;}`. The exclamation mark means "not"

Comment: @Brett I'll see what I can do. Also, I've tried using the debugging tools as best as I can and I have spent a good while going through everything but I cannot figure out why I'm having these issues. I think its more my JavaScript logic is wrong rather than the HTML -- but I could be wrong about that too.

Comment: Also your function doesn't do anything with the results stored into `labels`, so they are lost once exited, as if the function had never been invoked! Anyway you had better to post a **complete** exemple with .HTML part, and a description of the final result you're expecting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that is exactly your code since you can't have a function name loop... Apart from that, it does work.

https://jsfiddle.net/utswp2v0/

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function FindGoodFunctionName() {
        var authorDivs = document.getElementById('authorView').getElementsByTagName("div");
        var labels = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < authorDivs.length; i++) {
            var labelsFromDiv = authorDivs[i].getElementsByTagName("label");
            for (var x = 0; x < labelsFromDiv.length; x++) {
                // Just "Not" ! the if statement, don't need to have a empty one
                if (typeof labelsFromDiv.item(x) === "undefined" || labelsFromDiv.item(x) == null) {  }
                else {
                    labels[x] = labelsFromDiv.item(x);
                    labels[x].innerHTML = "Author 1";
                    labels[x].innerHTML = "Author 2";
                    labels[x].innerHTML = "Author 3"; // This is weird, assigning 3 different value to the same label
                }
            }
        }
    }

</script>

<div id="authorView">
    <div><label></label><label></label><label></label></div>
    <div><label></label><label></label><label></label></div>
    <div><label></label><label></label><label></label></div>
</div>

<input type="button" onclick="FindGoodFunctionName();" value="test" />
```

**Update**

Here's how it can look like with your html.

```
function FindGoodFunctionName() {
    var authorLabels = document.getElementById('authorView').getElementsByTagName("label");
    var labels = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < authorLabels.length; i++) {
        labels[i] = authorLabels[i];
        labels[i].innerHTML = "aaaa";
    }
}
```

Comment: I've made the changes you mentioned and I've clarified what I was actually trying to do. Still having trouble with it though. Thanks for the help!

Comment: See https://jsfiddle.net/utswp2v0/3/ where I've popped in a switch statement that assigns a new author to each label in a div... not sure what your original code was intended to do but as mentioned it was a bit weird assigning three different values.

Comment: @Mych I still have the same issue when I added your code, `x` never changes from 0. Why does that happen?

Comment: @errorreplicating you still haven't showed your html. The html I used is working with your code.

Comment: As the_lotus has proven the javascript works for the html shown... this points to your markup. If it is always returning 0 then based on what has been proven so far I would say you only have one label per div. If you supply your mark-up we would not have to second guess...

Comment: @Mych sorry for the delay but an example of the HTML is up, thanks for the help so far

Comment: @errorreplicating you have only 1 label in each div.... getElementsByTagName("label") will only return 1 value

Comment: @the_lotus how would I get each label into an array of labels so I can then manipulate them?