# When removing a child, also remove its associated HTML element without specifying its ID

Tags: javascript, html, input, removechild, setvalue

I have a program that adds input boxes when you click a button. A new ID in HTML for that box is created when it is added. The inputs are then inserted into a string that displays at the bottom. Inputs MUST have a length of 11 characters. I simplified this code from what I am actually working on, but here is the problem:

**Issue:**
When I add boxes and input values, it displays a string. Cool. However, when I remove a box (and make sure function getResponse() runs after), my string still displays the removed input's value. *I want those values/elements to not exist after I remove the child in JavaScript.* Even if I only set value to null, it still thinks the element exists and messes up my string.

**What I have tried**

- Setting input.value to null when running the function to remove child. This is in my code below. I have also tried setting input.id to null. Doesn't work, and I'm not even sure if this is allowed in syntax in this spot. I don't think it is, apparently. Even so, only setting the value to null instead of removing the element altogether will cause issues in my string when removing the child.
- Having a single button to remove the last input added instead of selective. This would work, the trouble is I'm not entirely sure how to go about it with the way my code is set up. This would be desperation, though, because *I want to user to be able to selectively choose which input they remove.* But if it's the only way, I could use some advice.
- Removing the element as you normally do by following removing the element[count]. This wouldn't  work the way I want it to since if you add 5 inputs, and the user removes the second, it will actually remove the 5th in value.
- Lastly I've tried input.removeChild(li) but get an error "node to be removed is not a child of this node"

```js
var count = 0;
let colorNumX = [];
window.createinput = function() {
  var field_area = document.getElementById('fields')
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  var input = document.createElement("input");
  input.id = 'field' + count;
  input.name = 'field' + count;
  input.type = "text";
  li.appendChild(input);
  field_area.appendChild(li);
  //create the removal link
  var removalLink = document.createElement('a');
  removalLink.className = "remove";
  removalLink.onclick = function() {
    input.value = null;
    field_area.removeChild(li);
    count--;

  }
  removalLink.appendChild(document.createTextNode(' X Remove'));
  li.appendChild(removalLink);
  count++;
}

document.querySelector("#createInput").click();
document.getElementById("field0").value = "1234567890X";

function getResponse() {

  var panel_date1 = document.getElementById("panelDate1").value;

  for (i = 0; i <= count - 1; i++) {
    colorNumX[i] = document.getElementById("field" + i).value;
  }

  var colorString1 = colorNumX.join(', ');

  if (colorString1.length > 22) {
    var FPlen1 = colorString1.length;
    var FPnewString1 = colorString1.substring(0, FPlen1 - 11) + "and " + colorString1.substring(FPlen1 - 11);
    var FPbestString1 = FPnewString1.slice(0, -17) + FPnewString1.slice(-17);
  } else {
    var FPbestString1 = colorString1;
  }

  var comment = "Per the number(s) " + FPbestString1 + " dated " + panel_date1 + ", this item description is redacted";



  document.getElementById("commentHere").innerHTML = comment;

}
```

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
}

.flex-container>div {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
  position: relative;
}

.close {
  position: absolute;
  right: 5px;
  top: -15px;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.close:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: darkred;
}

#createInput:hover {
  color: navy;
  opacity: 0.8;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.remove {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.remove:hover {
  color: darkred;
  opacity: 1;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<button id="addPanelDate" onclick="AddPanelClicked()">Add Panel Date</button>
<div class="flex-container">

  <div style="display: inline-block">
    <input id="panelDate1" onchange="getResponse()">Panel Date</input>
    <ul onchange="getResponse()" id="fields">
    </ul>
    <a id="createInput" onclick="createinput()">Add Panel Number</a>
  </div>
</div>

<p id="commentHere"></p>
```

Comment: There's too many things wrong with the code, I apologize for my bluntness, but you should start over.  I was halfway into an answer and realized that I was rewriting the whole thing.

Comment: I would have thought the problem lies in the first function of the JS code, ignoring the string work. Also ignoring iffy variable names, I'm not really sure how I would rewrite it to do the same action, which is why I'm asking the question. It almost seems like what I am trying to do is impossible.

Comment: No, not impossible at all, the majority of your code is functional but it's like a house of cards - very fragile and bloated as you can see with the errors popping up. I will post an answer to show you a better way to go about making a todo list...? It's a list function correct?

Comment: @zer00ne I think I actually found another question that helps tremendously. [This answer here illustrates what I'm trying to do on a very basic level](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14815741/14464184). I just console.log the array to see that it really is doing what I want. It's so much simpler... hopefully I can integrate it into everything else I'm doing. Concise code is better anyway

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A good JavaScript to add/remove items from/to array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14815560/a-good-javascript-to-add-remove-items-from-to-array)

Answer (score -1):

New:
Consider that right now in your code you are losing the reference to the specific fields you generate. Because there is no state recorded in any meaningful sense, you can't parse out which field to target based on the nested function. It's valid HTML to have unique IDs for your fields but when you go to delete them you are losing their distinct ID.
Have you considered writing a separate delete function and just adding a helper method with an argument that identifies that input? Doing something like this:

```
removalLink.addEventListener('click', function(){
    deleteInput("name"+count);
});
function deleteInput(str) {
// do stuff to delete item now that you know what it is.
}
```

Old: Seems like it could be an issue of scope. Have you tried changing the var declarations to let when you declare the items?
I'm just not confident that you're targeting what you think you are when the remove function is called.

```
  let field_area = document.getElementById('fields')
  let li         = document.createElement("li");
  let input      = document.createElement("input");
```

Comment: You have a closure around `count`. That will introduce problems since the handler will resolve the current value of `count` (i.e., the max) when it runs... rather than keeping value of `count` as it was when the handler was attached. Another thing to keep in mind is that the OP's code changes `count` up and down... which can result in `id` collisions on creation.

Comment: Agree with the above. The count won't always correspond to the input the user is trying to remove.

Comment: Updated to remove that recommendation. As I was typing it I realized it wouldn't work thanks to count being global.